# how to get hirearchy xml throug linq

Tags: c#

i want to generate the following xml through linq

```
<Items EntityTypeId="1" name="Organization">
  <Items id="2" name="Managment Team">
    <Items id="3" name="CEO">
      <Items id="6" name="VP Tech" />
    </Items>
    <Items id="4" name="CFO">
      <Items id="7" name="VP finance" />
    </Items>
    <Items id="5" name="CTO" />
  </Items>
</Items>
```

i have a list of data with id and their parent id.
can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article it should point you in the right direction.
http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx

Remember you'll need to add a reference to your project System.Xml.Linq